sha256 получение compute hash
имеются такие команды powershell
$inputBytes = "18", "52", "86", "131", "223", "140", "113", "9"
$sha256 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
echo $sha256.ComputeHash($inputBytes)

# в консоли получаю такой вывод
> 174, 212, 104, 226, 172, 255, 82, 242, 185, 157, 98, 82, 127, 138, 233, 124, 115, 117, 187, 23, 136, 77, 39, 152, 218, 206, 6, 206, 55, 15, 160, 25

как мне добыть эти значения в python? Я пробовал разные варианты но так и не понял как добыть эти значения как в выводе.
Проще говоря надо просто перевести код с powershell на python

import hashlib
    
input_data = ["18", "52", "86", "131", "223", "140", "113", "9"]
data = bytes(map(int, input_data))
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(data)
hash_result = sha256.digest()

print(list(hash_result))
    


[174, 212, 104, 226, 172, 255, 82, 242, 185, 157, 98, 82, 127, 138, 233, 124, 115, 117, 187, 23, 136, 77, 39, 152, 218, 206, 6, 206, 55, 15, 160, 25]


print(list(hash_result))

bytes(map(int, input_bytes))

и не меняйте тип переменной. то была list то bytes. такой код не типизируется. пс экономии по памяти тут у вас нет потому что gc будет работать после завершения функции.

Да, спасибо, стараюсь не путать типы.
